# jasperreports in struts2

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have tried to run jasper using Struts2 by passing integer parameters to it. But i am getting an error as

```
cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseTextField to field
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of type
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph
```

The code which i used i

```
parameterMap.put(parametername, param);
connection = dbc.getConnection(); 
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("jasper.jasper", parameterMap, connection);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"jasper.pdf");
```

Please can any one  help me to resolve this problem

Comment: Did you check your template with help of iReport (via preview function)?

Comment: Yup i have checked and able to produce correct preview

Answer (score 2):

This is known problem as you can [see](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/5520).

Probably you are using ***`commons-digester 2.1`***. You should use ***`1.7`*** version of **`commons-digester`** library.

***UPDATED:***

My working sample (standalone maven java application):

```
public static void testReport() {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");


        String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:d:\\path_to_db\db_file_name";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "sa", "");

        String reportSource = "d:\\path_to_jrxml\\simple.jrxml";
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connection);

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "d:\\output_path\\out.pdf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The snippet from pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all-1.0-jsr</artifactId>
        <version>05</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You can try to build your report with sample application like mine. 
I think your issue associated with classpath.

Comment: I have been using commons-digester 1.7 jar. but I am getting same error.

Comment: Can any one help me to export jasper report to PDF using java application

Comment: Can you post all libraries in your classpath?

Comment: I have added groovy library. Now I am able to run. But after running the report second tim I am getting an error as                        SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 1 column 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)

Comment: Do you use PostgreSQL? Is this a full stack trace?